# What is the best way for protecting sensitive data in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have more sensitive data in my `react-native` App. As you know AsyncStorage is not secure so I decided to encrypt my data with `crypto-js` lib, then store it with AsyncStorage.

But I dont know, what is the best ways to keep secure my App. Also there is a nice package: `react-native-keychain`, but I am not to use any third party libraries as it makes my release package larger and also makes slower the `app` launching.

Answer (score 2):

It is much **more secure** to use **iOS Keychain** / **Android Keystore** in **most cases**, especially if you are not a professional information security specialist. It also keeps data even if the app was removed.

This package will hardly make your app noticeably larger or app launching slower.

If you afraid of 3-rd party libraries you can always investigate the sources.

Comment: Thank you, being larger still is not a problem for me, but being fast when launching is much important. So Can you prefer me one of them or something else ?

Comment: @Muhammad I advise you to use react-native-keychain.